# HTML5 animation over a persistantly refreshing canvas

Tags: html, animation, canvas

Yo everyone!

I have been working on an Isometric Tile Game Engine in HTML5/Canvas for a little while now and I have a complete working game. Earlier today I looked back over my code and thought: "hmm, let's try to get this animated smoothly..."

And since then, that is all I have tried to do.

***The problem***
I would like the character to actually "slide" from tile to tile - but the canvas redrawing  doesn't allow this - does anyone have any ideas....? Code and fiddle below...

**Fiddle with it!** http://jsfiddle.net/neuroflux/n7VAu/

```
<html>  
<head>
<title>tileEngine - Isometric</title>
<style type="text/css">
* { margin: 0px; padding: 0px; font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; cursor: default; }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
var map = Array( //land
    [[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0]],
    [[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0]],
    [[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0]],
    [[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0]],
    [[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0]],
    [[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0]],
    [[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0]],
    [[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0]],
    [[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0]],
    [[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0]]
);
var tileDict = Array("http://www.wikiword.co.uk/release-candidate/canvas/tileEngine/land.png");
var charDict = Array("http://www.wikiword.co.uk/release-candidate/canvas/tileEngine/mario.png");
var objectDict = Array("http://www.wikiword.co.uk/release-candidate/canvas/tileEngine/rock.png"); //last is one more
var objectImg = new Array();

var charImg = new Array();
var tileImg = new Array();

var loaded = 0;
var loadTimer;
var ymouse;
var xmouse;
var eventUpdate = 0;

var playerX = 0;
var playerY = 0;

function loadImg(){ //preload images and calculate the total loading time
    for(var i=0;i<tileDict.length;i++){ 
        tileImg[i] = new Image();
        tileImg[i].src = tileDict[i];
        tileImg[i].onload = function(){
            loaded++;
        }
    }
    i = 0;
    for(var i=0;i<charDict.length;i++){
        charImg[i] = new Image();
        charImg[i].src = charDict[i];
        charImg[i].onload = function(){
            loaded++;
        }
    }
    i = 0;
    for(var i=0;i<objectDict.length;i++){
        objectImg[i] = new Image();
        objectImg[i].src = objectDict[i];
        objectImg[i].onload = function(){
            loaded++;
        }
    }
}

function checkKeycode(event) { //key pressed
    var keycode;
    if(event == null) {
        keyCode = window.event.keyCode;
    } else {
        keyCode = event.keyCode;
    }
    switch(keyCode) {
        case 38: //left
            if(!map[playerX-1][playerY][1] > 0){
                playerX--;
            }
            break;
        case 40: //right
            if(!map[playerX+1][playerY][1]  > 0){
                playerX++;
            }
            break;
        case 39: //up
            if(!map[playerX][playerY-1][1]  > 0){
                playerY--;
            }
            break;
        case 37: //down
            if(!map[playerX][playerY+1][1]  > 0){
                playerY++;
            }
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}

function loadAll(){ //load the game
    if(loaded == tileDict.length + charDict.length + objectDict.length){
        clearInterval(loadTimer);
        loadTimer = setInterval(gameUpdate,100);
    }
}

function drawMap(){ //draw the map (in intervals)
    var tileH = 25;
    var tileW = 50;
    mapX = 80;
    mapY = 10;
    for(i=0;i<map.length;i++){
        for(j=0;j<map[i].length;j++){
            var drawTile= map[i][j][0];
            var xpos = (i-j)*tileH + mapX*4.5;
            var ypos = (i+j)*tileH/2+ mapY*3.0;
            ctx.drawImage(tileImg[drawTile],xpos,ypos);

            if(i == playerX && j == playerY){
                you = ctx.drawImage(charImg[0],xpos,ypos-(charImg[0].height/2));
            }
        }
    }
}

function init(){ //initialise the main functions and even handlers
    ctx = document.getElementById('main').getContext('2d');
    loadImg();
    loadTimer = setInterval(loadAll,10);
    document.onkeydown = checkKeycode;
}

function gameUpdate() { //update the game, clear canvas etc
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,904,460); 
    ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(255, 255, 255, 1.0)"; //assign color
    drawMap();
}
</script>
</head> 
<body align="center" style="text-align: center;" onload="init()">   
    <canvas id="main" width="904" height="465">
        <h1 style="color: white; font-size: 24px;">I'll be damned, there be no HTML5 &amp; canvas support on this 'ere electronic machine!<sub>This game, jus' plain ol' won't work!</sub></h1>
    </canvas>
</body> 
</html>
```

**Edit:**
Please...?

Comment: You would highly recommend re-engineering the entire app to use a single canvas element, unless you have a very strong reason not to. It will probably save you more headache in the long run.

Comment: My app does use a single canvas - I was saying that having two canvas' was the only way I could think of doing it. Any ideas? :(

Comment: Hey I'll give this a crack when I have a free moment

Comment: I managed to get it working, but with a DIV above the canvas with a character animating via jQuery - I'd rather have this all in canvas: http://jsfiddle.net/neuroflux/tTyFB/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gamedev helped out:
https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/12058/smooth-animation-on-a-persistently-refreshing-canvas/12061#12061

Answer (score 1):

To animate with canvas, you have to redraw the whole affected section each frame, or your objects will leave a trail behind them. Each animation frame, before the sprite moves, you have to redraw the three or four tiles just behind him.

I'd suggest adding some extra states to your drawing function so that for each frame, some temporary distances are updated and the relevant tiles and sprite are redrawn. A global variable would block key input while the animation was running.

I'm too lazy to write it myself, but you should be fine. Have fun!

Comment: ahh, I think I understand - any chance I could implore you to reconsider being too lazy? ^_^

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't have time to write it.

Answer (score 0):

[Here's an example.](http://jsfiddle.net/tTyFB/8/) It isn't too accurate because I made it real quick.

Basically when a user pressed a button you want to initiate a countdown where each successive tick of the clock moves it (+1,+2) etc towards its goal. After some number of ticks it stops moving.

Edited to use Nick's modified example. See comments.